# Why is my owl carousel putting all my elements into one slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have a html structure like this:

```
<div class="header-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row iconstop">
            <div class="owl-top owl-theme">
              <div class="item">
                <i class="winkelmand"></i>
                <span>GRATIS VERZENDING</span>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <i class="hout"></i>
                <span>OVEN DROOG GARANTIE</span>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <i class="snel"></i>
                <span>LEVERING BINNEN 48 hr.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <i class="prijs"></i>
                <span>LAAGSTE PRIJS VAN NEDERLAND</span>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I need these elements to be slides in the carousel:

```
<div class="item">
    <i class="winkelmand"></i>
    <span>GRATIS VERZENDING</span>
</div>
```

But for some reason all element appear in one slide?

Why is that, I noticed a similar question but the answers to that were that he used an old jQuery version with a new owl carousel. That is not the case with me, I got the latest jquery version and the latest owl carousel files.

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/sxwm9ng3/

For as far as I can see I did everything as explained on the owl carousel site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the owl-carousel class

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

This class will give the necessary css properties for owl slider to work...

https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/2yjv7eza/2/

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was just an example class.